# Configure redmine that it responds on redmine.mydomain.com

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain, phusion-passenger, redmine

I installed redmine just a few minutes (or hours?) ago and it works fine at my root domain "mydomain.com". But this is not what I want. What I want is my root domain pointing to some public stuff and "redmine.mydomain.com" pointing to my redmine-Project.
Here is my `apache2.conf`-file:

```
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf
Include httpd.conf
Include ports.conf
Include conf.d/
Include sites-enabled/
ServerName *.mydomain.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin my.mail@mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/websvn/
        ServerName svn.mydomain.com
        <Location />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                order allow,deny
                allow from all
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "..."
                Require valid-user
                AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
<Location /websvn>
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "..."
        Require valid-user
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
</Location>
```

And the `000-redmine`-file inside sites-enabled/

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName redmine.mydomain.com    
    ServerAlias redmine.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/redmine/public
    <Directory /path/to/redmine/public>
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

A `mods-enabled/passenger.load`:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/passenger/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

And a `mods-enabled/passenger.conf`

```
PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/passenger
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
PassengerDefaultUser www-data
```

The `httpd.conf` is empty.

With this configuration I can access my redmine site via mydomain.com while redmine.mydomain.com does not even get resolved by my router.

What am I doing wrong? Pleas help me!

Comment: I think you need to configure your dns so that redmine.mydomain.com get resolved to your server.
what kind of authoritative DNS are you using for mydomain.com : a local DNS Server or your ISP DNS Serveur ?

Comment: @m0ntassar I don't know, could you please explain the difference? Maybe you should know: The hardware server itself is not mine, I have only a vServer on the real server anywhere (... I think its in Belgium).

Comment: ok so redmine.mydomain.com should be resolved to your vserver.
the simplest thing you can do is to ask your vserver support to add a dns wildcard entry *.mydomain.com pointing to your vsever ip address so that anything.mydomain.com get resolved to your vps

Comment: @m0ntassar Thanks! I did that and it works. redmine.mydomain.com does now show my redmine-interface but everything else too. Even a.mydomain.com shows my redmine-interface... What now?

Comment: Okay I have it, it was just that there was no default directive defined. Everything works perfect now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redmine.mydomain.com should be resolved to your vserver. the simplest thing you can do is to ask your vserver support to add a dns wildcard entry *.mydomain.com pointing to your vsever ip address so that anything.mydomain.com get resolved to your vps.